# Show Large Image in another DIV on Rollover of Thumb

Tags: jquery, image

I have a page that will have a full size product image and 4 (maybe more, maybe less) thumbnails.  As you rollover or click each thumbnail (either one) i would like the full size image to change.  Also the full size image should default to the first thumbnail.

I'm not exactly sure how to do this and there will be multiple product folders and product names but the naming convention will be similar in all.

I am guessing this would be jQuery (which is fine but I'm a bit new to) but here is the scenario:

```
<div class="fullsizeimage">show  /images/products/prod_1/produ_name_1_large.jpg here by default but change as the thumbs are rolled over or clicked.</div>

<div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="images/products/prod_1/prod_name_1_small.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="images/products/prod_1/prod_name_2_small.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="images/products/prod_1/prod_name_3_small.jpg"></a></div>
...
```

Here are the details:

- Image names will be images/products/prod_name/prod_name_1_small.jpg (100x100px) and images/products/prod_name/prod_name_1_large.jpg (400x400px) for all but prod_name and prod_1 will be different for each folder
- May be as few as 1 as many 10 thumbnails.
- Would like the first thumbnail to have it's fullsize counterpart loaded by default.

I'd prefer to do this only with jQuery and be reusable for everything fitting this pattern, if at all possible.

Thanks for any direction on this!

Comment: at first you should use class="thumbimage"

Comment: You are right, sorry about that, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would be a little more complicated than some simple JQuery, but I have seen several plugins for things like this that are very easy to use such as http://wayfarerweb.com/jquery/plugins/simplethumbs/

Comment: I think the first example on this page will do what I need.  The only thing I will need to add/modify is to make it also work on hover.  thanks!

Comment: a third action sometimes needed : zoom on image

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
<div class="fullsizeimage">
    <img src="/images/products/prod_1/produ_name_1_large.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="images/products/prod_1/prod_name_1_small.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="images/products/prod_1/prod_name_2_small.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="thumbimage"><a href="#"><img src="images/products/prod_1/prod_name_3_small.jpg"></a></div>



$('.thumbimage a img').on('click hover',function(){
    $('.fullsizeimage img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

but you have to change your html structure according to this, and you have to parse the url string and replace 'small' with 'large'

for img preloading you can use jquerys load() handler.

you can also add a hidden element with the large img url and parse this:

```
<div class="thumbimage">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/products/prod_1/prod_name_1_small.jpg"></a>
    <span class="url hidden">/images/products/prod_1/produ_name_1_large.jpg</span>
</div>

$('.thumbimage a img').on('click hover',function(){
    $('.fullsizeimage img').attr('src',$(this).parents('.thumbimage').find('.url').text());
});
```

Comment: if you're using jquery below 1.7 use delegate() instead of on()

Comment: thats just going to make the fullsize img a thumb isn't it?

Comment: yes, as mentioned, you have to parse the url string and replace 'small' with 'large' too

Comment: or if you use html5 you can set an additional data-large attribut to the thumb images and parse this with jquery